# how to insert/update sysdate using hibernate criteria?

Tags: hibernate

I am using spring with hibernate. my database is oracle. i want to update/save records with sysdate. we can insert/update sysdate using HQL. but i dont know how to insert sysdate using Criteria. please help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Criteria can't be used for insert or update queries. Only select. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: Hi Nizet, Thanks for your reply. if i want to insert/update records with sysdate do i need to use HQL alone? please suggest me.

Comment: no, you need to create/load the entity, and call setSomeDate(new Date()) on it.

Comment: Hi Nizet thanks for your reply. consider i have loaded an entity and modified date in it. now simply i need to call save/merge() right?

Comment: No, you don't need doing anything. Hibernate will automatically flush the modifications when necessary (at commit-time, at least). This is very important to understand. Read the Hibernate reference manual, and particularly this chapter: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-overview

Comment: Hi Nizet Thanks for sharing the link. my question is, consider employee entity i have retrieved from db to client side. now in the UI user has modified employee name. now on submit, to save the changes i should call session.saveOrUpdate() right? please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Why make your model depending in Oracle db?

Comment: take a look at this http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-timestamp

Comment: @UdoFholl that would only be suitable if the column is to be modified at each update.

Comment: that's why I said take a look. Maybe suits his needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a straightforward manner to use `sysdate` in a HQL insert/update statement. You can use the `current_timestamp()` function in HQL selects, but not in update/insert.

The question is not clear regarding if you need to do this update in some isolate situations, or if this column will *always* have the database's date in the moment of insertion/any update of the Entity.

- In case it is isolated updates that you need: You could workaround this by defining a property in your entity that would always hold sysdate, by means of [`@Formula`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html)`(value="select sysdate from dual")`. If this property was named `sysdate`, you could achieve this by doing `update MyEntity e set e.myDate = e.sysdate`.  Take into account that this approach introduces direct dependency to Oracle.
- In case the column is to be always updated with the database's timestamp whenever an update on the Entity occurs, use the approach @UdoFholl [pointed out](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-timestamp) in his comments, or use a trigger (if you have that level of control on the database) and annotate the field with [`@Generated`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/annotations/Generated.html).

Comment: It is a valid solution. But you are introducing a dependency in Oracle.

Comment: Since formula must be an SQL, and the content must be a compile time constant it is not possible. But your solution will work pretty well.

Comment: +1 to the answer, thanks for the credits, but are not necessary! hehe